# Convex polygon with two sides parallel in the same direction

Tags: geometry, polygons, convex-geometry

Let $P_1P_2\cdots P_n$ be a convex polygon (two consecutive points are distinct and three vertices can't be in the same line).

Is it possible that there exists $\vec{v}\neq \vec{0}$, $\alpha>0$, $\beta >0$ and $i \neq j$ such that $\vec{P_iP_{i+1}} = \alpha \vec{v}$ and $\vec{P_jP_{j+1}} = \beta \vec{v}$ ?

I think that this answer is no but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Why do you think it is not possible? Draw two parallel lines and mark segments on each. Finish by constructing the other sides, ensuring the shape is convex.

Comment: @BrianMoehring No three points can't be in the same line.

Comment: @K.Jiang Are you sure that you have $\alpha$ and $\beta$ >0 in this case?

Comment: Among six vectors of a regular hexagon (simple case), are not three opposite pairs parallel?

Comment: @Narasimham But if you walked around the regular hexagon in order, on the opposite sides you'd be facing the opposite direction.

Comment: @user37238 I see your point. Then I believe you would be correct.

Comment: I'm sure there is a simple proof, but I don't know it.  Up against the wall, you could construct the inward-pointing unit normal and take its cross product with $\frac{\vec{P_iP_{i+1}}}{P_iP_{i+1}}$ and show it's constant across each corner.

Comment: ok, OP is right obviously so, but a proof?

Answer (score 0):

Take a moment to convince yourself that the sum of the exterior angles of any polygon is $2 \pi$, where we define the exterior angle $\angle V_k$ as the rotation angle measured counterclockwise at a vertex $V_k$ from the entering segment $\vec{P_{k - 1} P_k}$ to the exiting segment $\vec{P_k P_{k + 1}}$, where the interior of the polygon is always on the left side of these segments (we traverse the vertices in a "counterclockwise" fashion). Clockwise angles are taken to be negative; i.e., each exterior angle satisfies $\angle V_k \in (-\pi, 0) \cup (0, \pi)$. The values $-\pi, 0, \pi$ are not included in this range since we do not consider a straight segment as multiple sides.

Next, notice that the situation in which two distinct sides $\vec{P_i P_{i + 1}}$ and $\vec{P_j P_{j + 1}}$ ($i < j$) are parallel and oriented in the same direction means that the sum of the exterior angles between these two sides obeys exactly one of the following:

$$\begin{cases}
\sum_{k \in \{i + 1, ..., j\}} \angle V_k = 0 && \text{and} && \sum_{k \in \{1, ..., i\} \cup \{j + 1, ..., n\}} \angle V_k = 2 \pi && \text{or} \\
\sum_{k \in \{i + 1, ..., j\}} \angle V_k = 2 \pi && \text{and} && \sum_{k \in \{1, ..., i\} \cup \{j + 1, ..., n\}} \angle V_k = 0
\end{cases}$$

That is, there exists some set of consecutive vertices whose exterior angles sum to $0$. Note that this set cannot be empty, because that would imply that $i = j$. This set also cannot contain just $1$ element, because that would imply that for some $k \in \{1, ..., n\}$, $\angle V_k = 0$. So, a set of at least two exterior angles sums to $0$, which implies that at least one $\angle V_k < 0$, and this will be a reflexive angle. Therefore, the polygon cannot be convex.